# Nuking realm and remove all references from redux's state

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm, react-redux, redux-middleware

The reason I'm asking is simple, the user can't log out because redux's store is still holding references to `RealmObject` instances that have already been deleted.

The user is presented with the following error as described in [Realms issue 1031](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1031)

[image: Accessing object of type X which has been invalidated or deleted]

I'm using the following packages that are related to the issue:

- "react-native": "^0.46.1"
- "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
- "react-redux": "^5.0.5"
- "realm": "^1.9.0",
- "redux": "^3.7.0",
- "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
- "redux-persist": "^4.8.2",
- "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"

Now, I have a few actions and reducers in which redux's store is updated.
When the user decides to nuke it all, I perform the following dance:

```
static logout() {
    try {
        // Remove everything from database
        RealmInstance.write(() => {
            RealmInstance.deleteAll();
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        if (__DEV__) {
            console.log(`Logout failed: ${ex.message}`);
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

The following function dispatches the result

```
export function logoutUser() {
    return dispatch => {
        if (Account.logout()) {
            dispatch(logoutSuccess());
        } else {
            dispatch(logoutError());
        }
    }
}
```

And for every reducer, I reset the state to it's initial state:
e.g. for the account reducer

```
export function accountReducer(state = { user: Account.User }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Types.SET_USER:
        case Types.GET_USER:
        case Types.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
        case Types.LOGIN_USER_ERROR:
            return state; // for example
        case Types.LOGOUT_USER:
            return {
                ...initialUserState,
                loggedOut: action.loggedOut,
            };
        default:
            return state // for example
    }
}
```

For the navigation reducer, I reset the routes and point to the login page.
This is where it starts all over again.

```
function nav(state = initNavState, action) {
    let nextState = null;

    // if (...) { ...
    } else if (action.type === 'LOGOUT_USER') {
        nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.reset(
            {
                index: 0,
                key: null,
                actions: [ NavigationActions.navigate({
                    routeName: 'Login'
                }) ]
            }
        ))
    } else {
        nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    }

    // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
    return nextState || state;
}
```

If I am correct, the issue exists because you call dispatch (redux's middleware/thunk logic) to spread the word throughout the application. But as far as I understand, dispatch invokes parts of the store that still holds references to the already deleted `RealmObject` instances. Hence the error.

Somewhere far down in the stacktrace, it points to `dispatch(logoutSuccess());`.
Is there another approach I should be using? I need the reducers to reflect on the logout command so their states are reset before the dispatcher is invoked.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/lolatravel/realm-react-redux can be useful.

Comment: @geisshirt That's good to know. But I doubt that approach fits our design model at this time. We use realm for caching purposes only. We don't need our project to be built around Realm. Second, it's experimental and I don't believe that this would solve the error mentioned above without re-writing the entire application logic